# DPLYR distinct exclude column in compare but keep in results?

Tags: r, dplyr, distinct, tidyverse

I have a data.frame similar to this structure:

```
a b c
1 1 A
1 1 A
1 1 BLAH
2 2 BLAH
2 3 C

df <- data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2),b=c(1,1,1,2,3), c=c("A","A","BLAH","BLAH", "C"))
```

I need to subset only the data that is distinct based on variables 'a' and 'b' but retain the variable 'c' in the results - but with a **condition**. If there are duplicates, keep only the version that is NOT equal to the "BLAH" value.

The output should look like this:

```
1 1 A
2 2 BLAH
2 3 C
```

So I have a distinct subset and chose to discard the "BLAH" version? Also, notice I kept only one of the "1 1 A" rows as desired.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
    group_by(a, b) %>%
    summarize(c = c[max(1, which(c != "BLAH"))][1]) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#      a     b c    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
#1     1     1 A    
#2     2     2 BLAH 
#3     2     3 C
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need to retain 'BLAH', one option is to `arrange` the 'c' column so that 'BLAH'  is the last row and then `slice` the first element of 'c'

```
df %>%
  group_by(a, b) %>%
  arrange(a, b, c == "BLAH") %>%
  slice(1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   a, b [3]
#      a     b c    
#  <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
#1     1     1 A    
#2     2     2 BLAH 
#3     2     3 C
```

By converting 'c' to `logical` and `order` it, `FALSE` will be ordered before `TRUE` in alphabetic order

Comment: I would keep rows with "BLAH" if there are no duplicates based on the other rows though. Would this retain rows with "BLAH" that have no corresponding duplicate?